# How to print selected database column in multiple labels?

Tags: c#, mysql

Please Help me to display selected column data from database in different label.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();       
        MySqlCommand countcmd = new MySqlCommand("select count(*) from category", con);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(countcmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        MySqlCommand inscmd = new MySqlCommand("select catname from category where cid > 0", con);
        string temp1 = inscmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        MySqlDataReader dr = inscmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++){
            ("label" & i).text = dr[i].ToString();
        }       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's totally wrong for a start, you can't access a control with (string).Text.

Next issue is what is creating these labels, if they are pre-created at design, how do you know you have enough, what are you going to do with the extra ones?

PS you should knock up a new Connection for each query and let connection pooling deal with caching instead of passing an instantiated one round, except in rare circumstances.

You should also dispose of your query objects, using is good for this, instead of relying on the GC to tidy up when you start running out of memory.

Also your query returns rows with one column, so you need a while loop.

First thing I'd do is return an `IEnumerable<String>` from the query.

e.g. something like

```
private IEnumerable<String> GetCategoryNames(String argConnectionString)
{
   using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(argConnnectionString))
   {
       con.Open()
       using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select CatName From Category Where cid > 0", con))
       {
           using(SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
           {
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                  yield reader[0].ToString();
              }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Then I'd knock up something that could scroll and instantiate labels in it with something like

```
private void AddNewLabels(argConnectionString)
{
  int count = 0;
  Point startPoint = new Point(0,0) // assuming this is where you want the first label to be in the scroll box
  labelSpacing = 20; // how far apart vertically should your column of labels be.
  foreach(String labelText in GetCatgoryNames(argConectionString))
  {
      Label label = new Label();
      label.parent = myScrollBox;
      label.Left = StartPoint.X;
      label.Top = Count * LabelSpacing + StartPoint.Y;
      label.Name = String.Concat'MyDynamicLabel'
      // etc
      label.Text = labelText;
      count++;
  }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DestroyPreviousLabels();
   AddNewLabels(conn.ConnectionString);
}
```

DestroyNewLabels would use `FindControl`, to FindControls with name starting with 'MyDynamicLabel'.
Or you could get a bit cleverer, and only destroy ones you don't need and only create more if you to. If you want to do that, consider a `List<Label>` and adding and removing from that, you'll have a count for a loop then, and you wont have to keep finding them as that's not brill performance wise.

Some ideas anyway and some refactoring opportunities as well, once you get it working.

NB, this was off the top of my head so may be a silly or two in it.

Answer (score 0):

use the page FindControl method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx

Comment: Well that's certianly part of the problem, not much use by itself though